# If someone goes to the casino with 10 euro and each time he gambles 1, where every time he has a chance of either losing or gaining find the chance

Tags: probability, contest-math, recursion, gambling

If someone goes to the casino with 10 euro and each time he gambles 1 euro, where every time he has a 40% chance of gaining 1 euro and a 60% chance of losing it, find the probability of him eventually reaching 100 euro.

I found that the recursive function for this is $P_n=\frac{3P_{n-1}+2P_{n+1}}{5}$ however this is as far as I got. Based on this recursive function, could you please show me how to solve the question?

Comment: Not sure how to get the answer but it should be basically zero.

Comment: It isn't actually

Comment: You have a linear difference equation and so $P_n = x^n$ can be used to find the roots. Boundary condition $P_{-1} = 0$ seems obvious, but I'm not sure what the other one would be off the top of my head.

Comment: @Michael so you know the answer?

Comment: @John the answer is  $\frac{(\frac{3}{2})^{10}-1}{(\frac{3}{2})^{100}-1}$ which equals approximately to $1.4*10^{-16}$

Comment: @John yes I know the answer, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Like I said, that's basically zero!

Comment: @John Yes ok :) I just wanted to make the exact value known

Comment: **EDIT** Misread the question, in this case the boundary conditions are $P_0 = 0$ and $P_{100} = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve the problem avoids solving the recurrence relation directly.

Let's say that the value of having $x$ euros is $(\frac32)^x$. I have chosen this function because now, the game is fair: from a state with value $(\frac32)^x$, the expected value of the next state is $\frac25 \cdot (\frac32)^{x+1} + \frac35 \cdot (\frac32)^{x-1}$, which simplifies to $(\frac32)^x$ because $\frac25 \cdot \frac94 + \frac35 \cdot 1= \frac32$.

Now, intuitively, if the game is fair, and you start with a value of $(\frac32)^{10}$, your expected value at the end should also be $(\frac32)^{10}$. But if you have a probability of $p$ of getting to $100$ euros, then:

- with probability $p$, you have a value of $(\frac32)^{100}$ at the end;
- otherwise, with probability $1-p$, you have a value of $(\frac32)^0 = 1$.

The expected value at the end is $(\frac32)^{100} \cdot p + (1-p)$. Solving $(\frac32)^{100} \cdot p + 1 - p = (\frac32)^{10}$ gives us $p = \frac{(\frac32)^{10}-1}{(\frac32)^{100}-1}$.

A way to make the intuition that the final expected value should equal the starting value is the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem). This also gives us some conditions to check for such an argument to work (which are satisfied in this case).